# Software to crop multiple images from a larger image

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, images

I would like to create some training data for a neural network. Let's say I have a photograph of lots of biological cells. I want to draw a box of a fixed size around each cell and save the selection as a separate file.

What software could accomplish this? I'd like something free and open-source, that works on Windows. Ideally I'd like a workflow in which I click on the image, a pre-specified box shows up, the file gets automatically cropped and saved, and then I can carry on clicking and cropping.

Answer (score 1):

Using the free and open source **GIMP [(link)](http://www.gimp.org)**, you could customize a script to crop as many images as you want via batch mode.

Here's a sample that is "close", but you'd need to edit to meet your needs.  It crops the images using the center as the centerpoint of the crop.

**Batch crop images... but keep centered:**

http://registry.gimp.org/node/27360

**Batch crop images, top left based:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324220/halfmanualy-crop-image

**Another custom AutoCrop for GIMP:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811378/how-do-i-write-a-custom-auto-crop-script-using-the-gimp

Comment: Thanks! Does GIMP allow you to use the mouse to position a box and then crop and save as a separate file? I want to keep creating smaller sub-images of the same size.

Comment: There's a "trick" for that.  Open up all the images as layers (drag and drop them all into the same image), then you can use a plugin like this to export each image out to a separate file: http://registry.gimp.org/node/28268